# Best plot to compare the distribution of pvalues from two variables - R

Tags: r, plot

I have two pvalues (v1 and v2) in a dataframe  - from two different methods of calculating pvalue.

example dataframe

```
 v1    v2
0.004 0.03
0.02  0.56
0.001 0.01
0.04  0.004
```

Now I would like to compare the distribution of these two pvalues between them and to the normal distribution. 
How can I achieve this in R ..
Any suggestions for plot types and packages..

The target results will be something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
?qqplot
```

might give you a starting point...
If you want to see if the pvalues are distributed normally, you might also want to check out Histograms which I find much more intuitive. But the breaks add possibilities to tweak so long until you have a plot that looks somewhat normal. You might want to try feeding [this page](http://www.bb-sbl.de/tutorial/verteilungen/ueberpruefungnormalverteilung) into a translator.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
hist(yourdf$V1, breaks=20, col="blue")
hist(yourdf$V2, breaks=20, col="blue")
```